# Spring Data Mongo: How to use the $each modifier?

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

How to use the `$each` modifier in the following findAndModify query of a MongoTemplate?

I have tried to find it in the Spring Docs, but nothing.

`answers` is the key in Mongo which holds an array.

`new answers` is an array which items should be added to the `answers` in Mongo.

```
mongoOperations.findAndModify(
    Query.query(...),
    Update().push("answers", newAnswers)
)
```

Comment: Something like `Update().push("answers").each(newAnswers)`

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Meanwhile I found it out also through the source code. I just wish Spring Docs would be better :/

Comment: Yw. Its there in [update](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb-template-update) section.

Comment: You are right thanks! Facepalm :)

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
Update update = new Update();

update.push("answers").each(newAnswers);

mongoOperations.findAndModify(
    Query.query(...),
    update
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You would want to do something like this :

```
Update update = new Update();
update.addToSet("answers", BasicDBObjectBuilder.start("$each", newAnswers).get());

mongoOperations.findAndModify(
    Query.query(...),
    update
)
```